# javascript not working for newly added innerhtml through jquery

Tags: jquery, html, innerhtml

I have following HTML structure

```
<table>
<tr>
   <div id="getData">
   </div> 
</tr>
</table>
```

I am using jquery's html() method to add dynamic contents to div id "getData" as:

```
  $('#valueResult').html(data);
    var data ="
<table><tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="test[1]" onclick="doSometing()" /> Test</tr></tr></table> 
    <table><tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="test[2]" onclick="doSometing()" /> Test</tr></tr></table> "
```

But the function doSometing() is never executed for any of the dynamically added checkboxes. 
why so ?

can anyone help me out ?

THX.

Answer (score 2):

A cleaner jQuery solution for a problem like this is to use `.live()` or even better `.delegate()`.

With this approach you should also give your `input element` an unique id and call:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#unique_input_id').live('click', function(){
      alert('clicked');
   });
});
```

Reference: [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/), .[delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)

Comment: This saved me so much time. .live was able to find the newly added DIV !  Thanks